# Popup view close button isn't working correctly

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am creating a popup view that displays on top of a blurred background. It seems to work fine apart from the fact that at the moment, occasionally when it appears, the close button doesn't work at all. This often seems to happen on the second use.

Here is my code:

```
override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if motion == .MotionShake {
        println("Shake")
        if randomImageContainer.alpha == 0 {
            var randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(randomImages.count)))

            lightBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)
            blurRandomView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: lightBlur)
            blurRandomView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
            view.addSubview(blurRandomView)

            randomImageContainer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 264, height: 308)
            randomImageContainer.center.x = view.frame.width/2
            randomImageContainer.center.y = view.frame.height/2
            randomImageContainer.image = randomImages[randomIndex]
            randomImageContainer.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
            view.addSubview(randomImageContainer)

            closeRandomButton.frame = randomImageContainer.frame
            closeRandomButton.addTarget(self, action: "closeRandomView:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            view.addSubview(closeRandomButton)
            view.bringSubviewToFront(closeRandomButton)

            UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
                self.randomImageContainer.alpha = 1
                self.blurRandomView.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    }
}

func closeRandomView(sender: UIButton!) {
    println("Activated")
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
        self.randomImageContainer.alpha = 0
        self.blurRandomView.alpha = 0
    }, completion: { (finished:Bool) in
        self.blurRandomView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.randomImageContainer.removeFromSuperview()
        self.closeRandomButton.removeFromSuperview()
    })
}
```

The alpha value for the image and blur view are being set in `viewDidLoad()`, so they definitely pass the if statement first time around.

I can't see the problem, so I was wondering if anyone could notice any issues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. There was two issues. First of all, I was removing the views from the SuperView which meant they couldn't be checked in the if statement. The other problem was that there was a different view being brought to the front elsewhere in my code which meant the button was unaccessible.